# Truth of Inequality based on the Third Axiom of Probability

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Could someone please confirm if using the third axiom of probability or otherwise, we can show whether the below is true, false or cannot be shown unless more information is given?

$$\Pr\left[X_{1}+X_{2} < \varepsilon\right]\leq \Pr\left[X_{1} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right]+ \Pr\left[X_{2} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right]$$

Here, $X_{i}$ are random variables from the same general distribution and $\varepsilon\in{\mathbb{R}}$

Please provide full steps and justification as applicable. If this is too simple or well-known, am happy to delete the question.

Comment: @b00nheT, Are you sure about this? Because the third axiom is $$P\left(\bigcup _{i=1}^{\infty }E_{i}\right)=\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }P(E_{i})$$ So the probability of sum of events is less than the sum of probabilities. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: @d.k.o., Could you please explain the reasoning behind your statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X_1+X_2<\epsilon\implies X_1<\frac12\epsilon\vee X_2<\frac12\epsilon$$ so that: $$\Pr\left[X_1+X_2<\epsilon\right]\leq \Pr\left[X_1<\frac12\epsilon\vee X_2<\frac12\epsilon\right]\leq \Pr\left[X_1<\frac12\epsilon\right]+\Pr\left[X_2<\frac12\epsilon\right]$$

Comment: thanks for this. So the $\lor$ operator is the union I presume. Am trying to understand the justification for the below, which is the key step, $$X_1+X_2<\epsilon\implies X_1<\frac12\epsilon\vee X_2<\frac12\epsilon$$  Seems correct, but do we need anything else to justify it? Please note, I could be missing something and will look once more shortly.

Comment: $\vee$ stands for "or" and corresponds indeed with union. What you call the key step can also be stated as: $A\subseteq A_1\cup A_2$ where $A:=\{X_1+X_2<\epsilon\}$ and $A_i=\{X_i<\frac12\epsilon\}$ for $i=1,2$. Then consequently $P(A)\leq P(A_1\cup A_1)$ and secondly $P(A_1\cup A_2)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)-P(A_1\cap A_2)\leq P(A_1)+P(A_2)$.

Comment: thanks for this clarification. I am trying to convince myself that $$X_1+X_2<\epsilon\subseteq X_1<\frac12\epsilon\vee X_2<\frac12\epsilon$$ Perhaps, this is a very immediate result or does this need to be shown or proven using other basic results? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: $\omega\notin\{X_1<\frac12\epsilon\vee X_2<\frac12\epsilon\}\iff X_1(\omega)\geq\frac12\epsilon\wedge X_2(\omega)\geq\frac12\epsilon\implies X_1(\omega)+X_2(\omega)\geq\epsilon\iff\omega\notin\{X_1+X_2<\epsilon\}$. So very immediate. Here $\wedge$ stands for "and".

Comment: Btw, I am fond of the symbols written by my baby-grandchildren (red your profile).

Comment: In case things are still unclear: in my comment I showed that $\omega\in(A_1\cup A_2)^c\implies\omega\in A^c$ (where $B^c$ stands for complement of $B$). That is exactly the same as $\omega\in A\implies\omega\in A_1\cup A_2$, so this proves that $A\subseteq A_1\cup A_2$.